# Delete a discord message in someone else's discord

Tags: discord

Is there a way to delete our own messages in someone else's discord channel ?
I use these lines to send the message automatically:

```
while True:

    sentence = random.choice(sentences)
    payload= {
        'content': sentence
    }

    header = {
        'authorization': "xxxxxxxxx"
    }

    r = requests.post('https://discord.com/api/v8/channels/xxxx/messages', data=payload, headers=header)
    
    secs = random.randint(61,75)
    time.sleep(secs)
```

and would like to delete the sent message right after being sent, but i don't find anyway to do so with the request delete method nor with discord.py api.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, but you should have the ID of the message, and also you should have the manage_messages permission as shown in the documentation:
https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=disconnect#discord.Message.delete